# Is $\sin(x)$ a monotonic function?

Tags: functions

> Is $y=\sin(x)$ a  monotonic function?

I want get some idea about the monotonic increase and monotonic decrease include function?
[not monotonic function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x659F.png)
because wiki said this is not monotonic function.[wiki monotonic description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)

Comment: Do you know the graph of  $\sin $ function ?

Comment: yes,it have some increase and decrease

Comment: i know monotonic increase and decrees ,i want get some idea about monotonic function

Comment: Actually increasing or decreasing of $\sin$ can be considered about only certain intervals, namely the interval of periodicity and it cannot be considered the whole of $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: sin(x) is one of eventual increasing and decreasing function,am i correct?

Comment: What do you mean by eventual increasing ?

Comment: Eventually Monotonically increasing:
if there is some **k ∈ N** such that a **n ≤ a n+1** for all **n ≥ k**

Comment: Ok! How it is one of that case ? can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: in **y=sin(x)**  x=0 to Pi/2 y is monotonically increase

Comment: x=Pi/2 to Pi **y** is monotonically decrease

Comment: Yes! but eventually increasing or decreasing does't happen!

Comment: The most-favored terminology is that of the Bourbaki project ( Nicolas Bourbaki didn't actually exist).  We say $f$ is increasing iff $x<y\implies f(x)\leq f(y)$ for every $x,y$ in the domain of $f.$ When $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in the domain then we say $f$ is strictly increasing.... Similarly for "decreasing" and "strictly decreasing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not monotonic. By definition, a monotonic function is one which preserves the order of the real numbers: that is, is $f$ is a function on the real domain or a subset thereof, and we are given two different inputs, one of which precedes the other - that is, if we let the inputs be $a$ and $b$, then $a \le b$, then this precedence is preserved after transforming them by the function, i.e. also $f(a) \le f(b)$ no matter what $a$ and $b$ are so long as both are valid as inputs (i.e. within $\mathrm{dom}(f)$).

So all you nee to ask is "does $\sin(x)$ scramble the order of any two real numbers?" And the answer is yes - take $x = \frac{1}{4} \tau$ and $x = \frac{3}{4} \tau$ (here $\tau = 2\pi$, I prefer this circle constant better) - the two points at which the sine graph reaches its extremes at +1 and -1, respectively, within the first wave cycle. The first point precedes the second, but +1 succeeds -1. The order is changed, and so $\sin(x)$ is not monotonic.

(FWIW, often in a casual calculus context one will hear a function which reverses the order *everywhere* also called a monotonic function or "monotonic decreasing function", but technically a better term from a theoretician's pov is "anti-monotonic" or "antitonic" function, since this is still a change of order. $\sin(x)$ is not this either because if we go now from $x = \frac{3}{4} \tau$ to $x = \frac{5}{4} \tau$, i.e. going into the next wave cycle, it now goes from -1 to +1, these points are not reversed, so it reverses some but not others, and thus is neither monotonic nor antitonic, but truly order-scrambling.)

Comment: can you give me any example for monotonic function

Comment: You want a monotone function? Consider $f(x) = x$ on the entire real line. Obviously monotone.

Comment: @teran teshara : There are many examples. Linear functions $f(x) = ax + b$, provided $a \ge 0$ (if $a < 0$ then it is antimonotone.), are one example. But also the power function $f(x) = x^n$ when $n$ is an odd positive integer.

Comment: @Sean Roberson : That post sounds a bit sharp. Why is that?

Comment: If a>b then f(a) <f(b)  for all domain monotonous

Answer (score 2):

$y=sin x$  is not an monotonic function on $R$.

But $y=sin x$ is monotonic on $[-π/2,π/2]$.

Look at the graph of $y=sin x$ then you can easily figure out whether it is monotonic or not.